# Doctrine2: Many-to-One delete relations on update

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, cascade, many-to-one

I have a software which can own many screenshots.

This is the software class:

```
class Software
{
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->screenshots = new ArrayCollection();
   }

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Screenshot", mappedBy="software", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\OrderBy({"sequence" = "ASC", "id" = "ASC"})
    */
   private $screenshots;


   public function setScreenshots($screenshots)
   {
       $this->screenshots = $screenshots;
   }
}
```

And this is the screenshot class:

```
class Screenshot
{
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Software", inversedBy="screenshots")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="software_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
   private $software;

   /**
    * @param mixed $software
    */
   public function setSoftware($software)
   {
       $this->software = $software;
   }
```

When I generate a few new screenshots, put them into a array collection and call
`$software->setScreenshots($newScreenshots)` with new screenshots everything works fine. The new screenshots are saved and they have the reference to the software.

But when I generate some other screenshots and call the method again, it doesn't delete the old screenshots. The new screenshots are just added.

Is there a way to have some kind of cascade option so the old screenshots are deleted? Or at least remove the reference to the software?

Answer (score 1):

You can let de database do the job (DBAL side):

```
user:
        targetEntity: User
        inversedBy: points
        joinColumn:
            name: user_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: 'cascade' #this is important for u
        fetch: EAGER
```

Comment: I just tried this and sadly it is not solving the problem. I would guess that it is because I'm not deleting the software. I'm just updating it.

Comment: so try onUpdate option - i don't know it will be work or not even exists :)
Experiment with lib !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to remove them manually:

```
foreach ( $software->getScreenshots() as $scrshot){
    $em->remove($scrshot);
}
$software->setScreenshots($newScreenshots);
```

But, apart from this solution have you tried defining `orphanRemoval` on inverse side or relation? Maybe that would help, but I am not sure:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Screenshot", mappedBy="software", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"sequence" = "ASC", "id" = "ASC"})
 */
private $screenshots;
```

Comment: I thought about the manual removal but I don't feel comfortable having this logic in my entity. The orphanRemoval is only allowed on the software side and there it is not working as I need it to.

Comment: Yes, I would also avoid merging entity with removal logic so I would put it into controller/service.

Comment: I'm using an objectbuilder which denormalizes jsons. So sadly I wouldn't be able to put the logic somewhere besides the entity.